# Passing a variable from a form input to a flask URL

Tags: flask

I have a dummy project in Flask, which consists in a web form, where you fill in 3 cities, which are then printed upon submition.
This is my  **init**.py file:

```
@app.route('/average_temperatures/<city1>/<city2>/<city3>', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def results_temperature(city1, city2, city3):
    return "The cities are: {}, {}, {}".format(city1, city2, city3)
```

The function works, but I am unable to pass the variables from the form straight into the function, as parameters.

**edit**:

My goal is to have the city variables as part of the URL in the clean form of /city1/city2/city3.

This is the form:

```
<div class="input-group">
<form action="{{ url_for('results_temperature', city1=city1, city2=city2, city3=city3) }}" method="POST">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="City 1" name="city1"></input>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="City 2" name="city2"></input>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="City 3" name="city3"></input>
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 20px;"></div>
```

Filling out the form results in a URL

> http://example.com/average_temperatures///

So I evidently fail to pass the form fields in the form action part.
Any hits are appreciated, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You should get the cities from the request.form variable.

```
@app.route('/average_temperatures', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def results_temperature():
return "The cities are: {}, {}, {}".format(request.form['city1'], request.form['city2'], request.form['city3'])
```

In your HTML form:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('results_temperature') }}" method="POST">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="City 1" name="city1"></input>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="City 2" name="city2"></input>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="City 3" name="city3"></input>
</form>
```

Comment: This is what I had initially, but I am looking for a workaround to have the variables as part of URL in the clean form of /city1/city2/city3,  I can't get it work via htaccess so I thought I could do it on the flask side

Comment: The OP asked for a way to put URI parameters and you tell them to use the POST's body / GET's url `?param=value` which is not the point of that question.
For other users, here is [what you're probably looking for](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/flask_variable_rules.htm)